Websocket - Client is still with https-200 even though server have successfully upgraded the connection and shared back 101 response
I am having an application using websocket for communication but randomly observing that the browser is still with https & status 200 instead of 101, even though the handshake is successful and server has responded with 101.

Not observing any functional issues or errors.
Necessary headers are being passed.

Have anyone faced this anomaly with websocket?
Thanks in advance for the info.
Tried debugging & verified no functional issues.
Expecting the browser to be with 101 response code once handshake is successful.
